# Computing value just for the last row of same value of column

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I use the following code:

```
    i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , 
               sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$v1


    SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
    SRC2
```

I would to change the line code so only the last occurrence of the same values of `sequenceID` will contain the `Co` value and not all the lines as in this code.

The current output (each line has value "Co"):
"

```
sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1     0.67
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0     0.67
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1     0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"     0     0.5
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"    1     0.5
```

The required output (only the last line of the same "sequenceID" contains value "Co":

```
"sequenceID" "transactionID" "eventID" "items"  "Exist" "Co"
"1" 42207993       1577          1        "OV50"     1
"2" 42207993       6048          2        "OV11"     0  
"3" 42207993       1597          3        "OV148"    1       0.67
"4" 57237976       12423         1        "OV46"     0
"5" 57237976       12589         2        "OV197"    1       0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the required code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(SRC2)

i1 <- SRC2[, Co:= as.character(round(sum(Exist)/.N, 2)) , sequenceID][, .I[1:(.N-1)], sequenceID]$V1

SRC2[i1, Co:= '']
SRC2
```

The last part of i1 has to contain V1 (in Capital letter)